# Intel Pentium E5700 and RAM?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, ddr3

I just ordered DDR3 PC3-12800 1600MHz, in a single 8GB module, and my motherboard has 4 slots but can support a max of 8GB of RAM, will my CPU be able to use this RAM to it's full potential? Will it work at all?

Also, (I'm SURE this is a stupid question) but can I get around that 8GB limit? I'm using this computer as a Blu-ray server, so any extra ram would be nice.

~Edit~
Edited the title to represent the actual CPU, I had Googled the Acer Aspire M3900 and it said it had an Intel Pentium E6700 CPU, when it only has an Intel Pentium E**5**700 CPU

Comment: Please post the MB Model, that's important.

Comment: This depends on your chipset more... Core2Duos had the memory management unit still in the NorthBridge... Please add the exact make and model of your board to be able to help.

Comment: It's an OEM board, by Acer. :/

Comment: @MarcusJ - You would then have to provide the exact laptop model you have.  The answer you seek is in the documentation for your laptop.  Check the Intel product information to see how much memory the CPU installed on your particular laptop supports.

Comment: It's a desktop, Acer Aspire M3900-U3802.

Comment: @MarcusJ - Have you checked the manual yourself.  You are expected to research your problem before asking a question like this.

Comment: I've tried tracking down that manual for months actually, for this and that, and it always alluded me. even searching Acer's site won't bring it up, you have to search for a the main model number, AKA everything before the "-" and then the guide doesn't even list the specs my computer has.

Answer (score 3):

[This page on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_chipsets) lists all the relevant chipsets. As per that it won't work for sure if you have these chipsets:

- 9xx series (no DDR3 in there)
- G3x series (no DDR3 in there)
- P31 chipset (no DDR3)
- G41 chipset (4GB DDR3 only)

*Might* work with these:

- P35
- G4x (but not G41!)
- B4x series
- Q4x series
- X38
- X48

As the highest amount listed is 16GB, and maximum RAM socket count is 4, which implies that it is to be used with 4GB modules to achieve that, I'd say there is a chance that it won't work, but I can't say it for sure. You have to consult the specs of the motherboard to be sure...

Also, all of the relevant chipsets can use dual channel operation, which can have a very good effect on speed. In your case, I'd opt for a 2x4GB set, if it is possible to swap it, as it is most likely supported, and also performs better.

<del>**EDIT**
It *seems* to be a G45 chipset... I can only say *seems*, as I was not able to properly identify the device behind the device ID. This is a chhipset that has odds that it will work with the RAM, but I can't be sure...</del>

**EDIT2**
Bad news:

The [spec page for Acer M3900](http://panam.acer.com/acerpanam/desktop/2010/acer/aspire/AspireM3900/AspireM3900sp2.shtml) clearly states:

> Memory1, 3, 4, Dual-channel 1066 MHz DDR3 SDRAM support:
>
> - **Up to 2 GB per memory module**
> - Upgrade option with four unbuffered DIMM slots

And the chipset is:

> Chipset Intel® G43 Express Chipset

Comment: Device manager says that I have a "Intel 4 Series Chipset PCI Express root port - 2e21"